# When using Phonegap and Facebook JavaScript API I get a blank page

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm doing an app with Phonegap and I use the Facebook JavaScript API. The problem is every time I  do a "fb parse xml" I get a blank page in the browser. So the Facebook API opens a browser with the "about:blank" page.

What may I be doing wrong to allow that to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `display=page` in your request instead of `display=pop-up`.

For example:

```
https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=********&skip_api_login=1&display=page
```

It's resolved same issue in my application.